# How can I get response from webservice in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I want to get the data response from my login webservice. Here is my web service 
 http://41.128.183.109:9090/api/Data/getloginer?medid=a&pass=a
 (for testing). Here is my code:

```
$("#login").click(function () {
    var url = "http://41.128.183.109:9090/api/Data/getloginer?medid=a&pass=a";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'Get',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.Medical_id);
        },
    });
});
```

The `alert()` shows me `undefined`. Please advise on what the problem could be.

Comment: Check the console for errors. I would guess you're being stopped by the Same Origin Policy. Is the web service you're calling local to the website? If so, use a relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is an array, so in order to get that field you have to iterate the result or get the first item:

```
for (var i in data) { 
   console.log(d[i].Medical_id);
}
```

Or you can simply get the first result:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://41.128.183.109:9090/api/Data/getloginer?medid=a&pass=a',
  type: 'Get',
  success: function (data) {
        alert(data[0].Medical_id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The JSON  result you are getting is :

[{"$id":"1","id":8,"Medical_id":"a","Password":"a","Name":null,"Email":null,"gender":null,"Type":null}]

use for each to iterate through  the results  or 
instead of this  you  can check the result like this :    
var data = [{ "$id": "1", "id": 8, "Medical_id": "a", "Password": "a", "Name": null, "Email": null, "gender": null, "Type": null }] 
alert(data[0].Medical_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you develop application in localhost then refer this questions also. 

["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

If you are using chrome, then use this link to use CORS enable plugin.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US 

 hope this will help